# If $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, then $gf$ is one-to-one.

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-verification, intuition

I'm aware that there is a thread about this proof. However, I have a slightly different approach which I can not verify myself - hence, this thread.

*Proof*.

If $\,g(f(a_j))=g(f(a_k))$ and $g$ is injective, then $f(a_j)=f(a_k)$.

If $\,f(a_j)=f(a_k)$ and $f$ is injective, then $a_j=a_k$.

Therefore, if $\,g(f(a_j))=g(f(a_k))$ and $g$ and $f$ are injective, then $a_j=a_k$ and thus $g(f(a))$ is an injective function if $g$ and $f$ are injective.

Is it correct?

In a logical context, I have some troubles getting this proof intuitively.
All I can see is usage of implications and thus I don't fully understand the full picture...

Comment: Proof seems fine

Comment: The proof is correct. What full picture are you trying to obtain? Are there other things you're being asked to prove that fit in with this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to see this intuitively is by "drawing arrows". An injective function is basically a set of arrows, no two of which go to the same point (see the picture below). Now suppose instead of just an injection $X\to Y$ we also had another injection $Y\to Z$, and we wanted to compose them. Then the resulting "set of arrows" from $X\to Z$ will also have no two arrows ending up at the same place, because two arrows starting out at different places end up at different places in $Y$, then therefore end up at different places in $Z$. Try drawing arrows to convince yourself of this!

[image]

(source of image: wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

This proof is fine. Well done. To gain a higher perspective, consider studying (at least the basics of) category theory.

One thing I can say - and this is nitpicking here - is that you have neglected to define the $a$s.

Here's another thing: the subscripts are unnecessary. Just use $j$ and $k$ (and be sure to define them!).